# Adding Radio Button to Advanced Custom Field

Tags: radio-button, positioning, advanced-custom-fields

I'm pretty new to ACF. I am editing this page: http://pear.staging.wpengine.com/schizophrenia-semi-final/ which has an ACF for the intro image and another for the intro text. In the template, this is the code:

```
<?php $bg1 = (get_field('pear_intro_image')) ? get_field('pear_intro_image') : ''; ?>
<section id="intro" class="section" style="background-image: url('<?=$bg1[sizes][large]?>');">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
        <?= get_field('pear_intro_text') ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The style "background-image" sets the position of the image to 'center center'. The client wants to remove that class and instead add a radio button to the ACF with the option for aligning it to the top, center or bottom.

I am not sure how I would go about this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Choose radio button as a field. You're presented with the value and the label. The value is what is passed through when you do the `<?php the_field()?>`. The label is what the person in WP sees in the admin area when making a selection.

So if you have radio buttons that are:

left center : Left
center center : Center
right center : Right

They will see "Left, Center, Right" as choices.
`<?php the_field('background_position')?>` would output "left center" for instance, if they chose Left.